# How to avoid @search.score from Azure Search result?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

How to avoid @search.score from Azure Search result?

When I execute

```
var searchOptions = new SearchOptions
{
   Select = { "id" },
};
await _searchClient.SearchAsync<object>("*", searchOptions);
```

each record returned has a property called `@search.score`

Is there a way to avoid it? I only need the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#response), I would say it is not possible to omit `@search.score`.

```
"@search.score": document_score (if a text query was provided)
```

Just thinking out loud, one possible way would be to have your search result return a typed model instead of a generic object. So you could create a class called `MyDocument` that has one public property called `id`.

When you do something like:

```
await _searchClient.SearchAsync<MyDocument>("*", searchOptions);
```

You will get a collection of `MyDocument` objects which will only have `id` property.

Comment: That is what I do but unnecessary bytes are still getting sent over the wire. I am dealing with millions of rows and for now I will just waste a few bytes per record.

Comment: Agreed with Gaurav, it is not possible at this time to omit the score. We do track feature requests, so if you would like to add one, please feel free to do so here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9325d19e-0225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8